# Link not working inside floated div

Tags: html, css

The links in the div with Class "ad_left" won't work and I can't figure out why. I tried it on 3 different browsers and the behavior is the same. I'm baffled.

```
<style>
#ad_content .ad_left{
float: left;
margin-right: 12px;
position: relative;
}
#ad_content .ad_right{
position: relative;
}
#ad_content .ad_expand {
position: absolute;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
}
</style>
<div id="ad_content">
    <div class="ad_row">
        <div class="ad_left">
            <a href="#"><img src="images/ad_frleft.jpg" /></a>
            <a href="#"><img class="ad_expand" src="images/expand.png" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="ad_right">
            <a href="#"><img src="images/ad_frright.jpg" /></a>
            <a href="#"><img class="ad_expand" src="images/expand.png" /></a>
        </div>
    </div><!-- End Ad Row #1 -->
</div><!-- End Content -->
```

Comment: "won't work" how exactly? What happens?

Comment: Issue is one Image is at right side./ is that issue./

Comment: Please check this http://jsfiddle.net/sCbDR/

Comment: can you give an image to show what you want your images to take place?

Comment: @AkshayJoy jsfiddle is empty.

Comment: Emty because there is no Image.. please chekc the Styles and Divs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `.ad_right` has a width of 100% (default value for block elements) and is covering your `.ad_left`. If you set a background to `.ad_right` you will see it better.

The solution is float `.ad_right`:

```
.ad_right {
  float: right;
}
```

There's also a little trick that `.ad_right` fills *automagically* the space left to the right from your left floated elemenet, which maybe you prefer to use. If so, **don't float `.ad_right`** and just set an overflow on it:

```
.ad_right {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Another way is just **delete the relative position from `.ad_right`**. But not sure if you need it there or not.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell what your goal is without more information.

I do see one issue: by setting position:absolute on the img tags, you are effectively removing them from the anchor tags.  The anchor tags then have no content, and thus no size.  You could solve this by setting the absolute positioning on the anchor tags, instead of the images:

```
<div id="ad_content">
    <div class="ad_row">
        <div class="ad_left">
            <a href="#"><img src="images/ad_frleft.jpg" /></a>
            <a class="ad_expand" href="#"><img src="images/expand.png" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="ad_right">
            <a href="#"><img src="images/ad_frright.jpg" /></a>
            <a class="ad_expand" href="#"><img src="images/expand.png" /></a>
        </div>
    </div><!-- End Ad Row #1 -->
</div><!-- End Content -->
```