# Links not working inside div

Tags: html, css

I think this question is related to [Link not working inside floated div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16382431/link-not-working-inside-floated-div) but I still can't figure it out.

I have a div as follows:

```css
.fullwidthimage {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
}
.imageoverlay {
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 15px;
  width: 100%;
}
#homepagebutton {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 100;
  bottom: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 60px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -100px;
  font-size: 25px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: orange;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="fullwidthimage">
  <img class="noround imageundertext smallimg" src="http://placehold.it/600x800">
  <img class="noround imageundertext midimg" src="http://placehold.it/1000x1000">
  <img class="noround imageundertext bigimg" src="http://placehold.it/3200x1300">
  <img class="noround imageundertext xlimg" src="http://placehold.it/5000x1500">
  <h1 class="imageoverlay">Title Here</h1>
  <a href="#getstarted" id="homepagebutton">Get Started</a>
</div>
```

The different images are using a CSS media query to display/hide at different sizes. The whole thing is a full width image with a text title and 'button' (that's actually just a link styled to look like a button) over the top of the image.

Whatever links I put inside that div won't work - the text shows on the page, but nothing happens if you mouse over.

Why?!

Links placed immediately outside of the div on the same page work just fine, so I don't think it's anything to do with other containing divs there.

I'm assuming from that previous question asked that it's something to do with the positioning, but I can't make it work.

Thanks!

Comment: @alldani There is a [mcve]. Where are you looking at?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you give a `-1` in `z-index`, it goes behind `body`. So the whole `div.fullwidthimage` becomes unclickable or unaccessible. So, give `z-index: 1` as the starting point.

```css
.fullwidthimage {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;               /* Change this! */
}
.imageoverlay {
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;               /* Increase this! */
  top: 15px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Sorted! I hadn't realised that it could send it behind the body, that -1 z-index was straight out someone else's code. Thanks.

Comment: @ts123 Yea, better have a look at the manual before you are taking someone else's code. `:)`

Comment: No kidding.... I'm only just learning so copying a few bits of code is pretty fundamental right now. I'd just got it from googling 'how to get text to overlay an image' or something like that. So much learning to do yet.

Comment: Ha ha... @ts123 I was asking you to check what `z-index` does... `:)`