# Btn classes is not clickable in react.js?

Tags: reactjs

Here I am creating a button in which when I click on button, it redirects to another page. Now the problem arises when I am setting `className="btn"`. If I didn't use `btn` in `className` then this div is clickable but when I am setting `className="btn"` then This button is not clickable.

```
<div className="btn col">
   <Link to={`/category/${category.slug}`}>{category.name}</Link>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, If you can show on your post your css code, It will be helpful to understand what is happening and to let people test it.

## First Solution (useHistory)

I do not know if you have experience using React Router (https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks) but what you can do is to add an onClick event to the div element and call history.push(). I let you an example below

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

function Home() {
  let history = useHistory();

  function handleClick() {
    history.push("/page");
  }

  return (
    <div onClick={handleClick}>
      Go to a page
    </div>
  );
}
```

## Second Solution

I am not sure about what is happening with your css code but I am sure about is a z-index problem. Probably div is over your link component and you cannot click on it. I've found this post ([Links not working inside div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41317893/links-not-working-inside-div)) check if implementing the solution, it solvers your problem